# Proof of the Adjunction Formula on smooth projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $Y\subset X$ be some smooth hypersurface, then the adjunction formula tells us that $$\omega_Y = (\omega_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Y)\vert_Y$$ but I don't understand why this is true. My first approach was to try to use Serre duality, and the fact that $\omega_X\cong\omega_X^\circ$ and $\omega_Y\cong\omega_Y^\circ$ to prove it, and setting $\omega'=(\omega_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_Y)\vert_Y$, but I ran into a hitch in trying to define $$t: H^{n-1}(Y,\omega')\to k.$$ Now, my thought was to define the closed immersion $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$, and to think of $\omega'$ as $i^*(\omega_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}i_*\mathcal{O}_Y)$ to use a push-pull type formula, but unfortunately the stars are in exactly the wrong place to make use of that. I also know that we should have some map $$i^*:H^{n-1}(X,\omega_X\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}i_*\mathcal{O}_Y)\to H^{n-1}(Y,\omega')$$ but this doesn't seem especially helpful.

What is the correct way to prove this formula?

Comment: You are trying to prove the wrong thing: the formula should have $\mathcal O(Y)$ rather than $\mathcal O_Y$. The point is that $\mathcal O(Y) \mid (Y)$ is the normal bundle of $Y$. The proof (which is in e.g. Hartshorne II.8 if I remember correctly) is elementary stuff about the tangent and cotangent bundle, and has nothing to do with cohomology.

Comment: You just need to know how determinant (i.e top alternating power) and exact sequence interact together.

Comment: Is the determinant map a functor?